# How to post json object to web api and then receive response?

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, authorization

I have php code, it works fine, but the customer want to convert it into javascript.
I have a web api service url, i need to authorize by username:password then post a json object to the web api url to receive data(also in json type).

Here is my php code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $MyWebApiUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json' )
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);           //  curl authentication

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$Username:$Password");       //  curl authentication

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$MyPostJsonObject);

$str=  curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($str)
```

This is my javascript code so far

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: MyWebApiUrl,            
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic  XXXXXXXXXX");},
            data: JSON.stringify(MyPostJsonObject),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: alert("An error occurred: ")
        });
```

I always receive "An error occurred: ".

Hope you can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Define error function as

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('An error', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown );
}
```

to understand why your request can't pass.

Comment: jqXHR object contains information about request. For example, status and responseText properties contains main information. Edit alert message to `alert('An error', jqXHR.status, jqXHR.responseText );`. See http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp